# stop windows 7 complaining about the firewall

Tags: windows-7, router, firewall, windows-firewall

Is there a way to stop Windows 7 complaining about the fact that ive turned the default firewall off. Whilst i am on my home network i dont want to run the windows firewall as im behind a router, but windows periodically complains that i have it switched off even though it isnt necessary?

is there anyway to prevent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you actually launch Action Center (the tray application that fusses at you), you can disable the alerts from inside the main interface.